# C# Listview LabelEdit

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, edit

I want to edit a column of a `listview` in my winform's application and I do it by Setting `LabelEdit = true` and writing the below code in `KeyDown` event

```
if (e.KeyData == Keys.F2 && lvwColumns.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
                lvwColumns.SelectedItems[0].BeginEdit();
```

After editing the label, how can I validate the entered value?  If the value is null or empty, I'd like to prevent it from saving.

[image: Before Edit]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for the `ListView.AfterLabelEdit` Event.

```
private void lvwColumns_AfterLabelEdit(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.LabelEditEventArgs e)
{
   if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(e.Label))
   {
         e.CancelEdit = true;
         MessageBox.Show ("Please enter a valid value.");
         return;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this [AfterLabelEdit MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.afterlabeledit(v=vs.110).aspx):

Sample on form:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        lvwColumns.LabelEdit = true;

        lvwColumns.AfterLabelEdit += lvwColumns_AfterLabelEdit;
    }

    private void lvwColumns_AfterLabelEdit(object sender, LabelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.Label))
            e.CancelEdit = true;
    }
```